# Como criar um range de uma arquivo xls, que é alimentado semanalmente?

Tags: r, dataframe

Como criar um *range* na função `read_excel`, do pacote `readxl`, onde existe o corte inicial e o final fica em aberto, pois é alimentado semanalmente.

`b_aberto <- read_excel("Boletos_em_ABERTO.csv", range=c("A10:    "))`

Comment: Acho que seria mais simples você excluir as linhas iniciais `skip = 9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar a função [`cell_limits`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/cellranger/html/cell_limits.html) do pacote `cellranger` para definir um retângulo em aberto. O formato é

- `ul` - vetor que identifica o canto superior esquerdo (**u**pper **l**eft) da  célula do rectângulo.
- `lr` - vetor que identifica o canto inferior direito (**l**ower **r**ight) da  célula do rectângulo.

E o código será algo como (não testado):

```
library(readxl)
library(cellranger)

# A10 - linha 10, coluna 1
read_excel("Boletos_em_ABERTO.csv", range = cell_limits(c(10, 1), c(NA, NA)))
```